# Mongoose forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database of 50,000 users and I need to loop over each one and update them with some dynamic values per user.

I've tried using

```
users.find({}).forEach((user) => { console.log('Some code.') })
```

But it says that forEach is not a function - from research it looks like this is a mongodb function but not a mongoose function.

I've tried using just `find({})` but of course the results will be cursor based, and it also doesn't actually console.log anything for me.

I've also tried using `.stream()`, but that's also returning not a function and I've also tried using `.batchSize(100)` but that also does not return anything in the console log when testing.

I've looked into updateMany but that is only good for updating the same static value in a field.

I'm a little lost on how to proceed forwards in a performant way. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Try `users.find({}).toArray().forEach`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit as far as I know that'll attempt to find all 50,000+ documents in one go and transform into an array? that would not be performant. I need a way to traverse/batch process the cursor

Comment: Did you try? Nowadays in 2022 an array of 50k elements should not be a problem anymore.

Comment: What is your function? I guess it can be done with an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit javascript is still single threaded though so for each user when i perform a calculation it's going to kill my cpu and slow my application down, afaik ? This will be an hourly cron job btw

Comment: Again, what is your function and did you actually try it? Instead of node.js you can run the script also in mongo shell. There the [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#std-label-find-cursor-methods) method returns  `cursor` which provides [forEach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#mongodb-method-cursor.forEach). The new [mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/) shell is also a node.js shell Another option is to use Callback function: `users.find({}, function (err, docs) {})`

Comment: Yes I tried it, as explained in the original post. I ended up resolving the issue using the eachAsync method. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The `Model.find()` function returns a promise, not an array.

You will need to use `await` or a callback to actually execute the find and retrieve the result array before iterating.